problem updating <H1> Element HTML Using JavaScript
I'm making a tic-tac-toe Game and now I'm doing the Winner function. After one player Win, my h1 (players) is supposed to say ${playerOne} Won Or ${PlayerTwo} Won But this is not happening. After someone Wins, the h1 is not changing, it keeps on "playerOne's turn", "PlayerTwo's turn)


const cells = document.querySelectorAll(`.cell`);
let playerOne = "";
let playerTwo = "";
let currentPlayer = false;
let submitOne = false
let submitTwo = true
let board = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
let winCombinations = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [2, 4, 6]
];
const players = document.getElementById(`h1Id`)

function game() {
  document.getElementById("submitNameOne").addEventListener("click", () => {
    playerOne = document.getElementById("playerOne").value;
    submitOne = true
  });

  document.getElementById(`submitNameTwo`).addEventListener(`click`, () => {
    playerTwo = document.getElementById("playerTwo").value;
    submitTwo = true
    checkSubmit()
  })


  cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
    cell.addEventListener(`click`, () => {
      if (board[index] === ``) {
        board[index] = currentPlayer;
        if (currentPlayer === false) {
          cell.textContent = `X`;
          currentPlayer = true;
          checkWinner()
          players.textContent = `Vez de ${playerTwo}`
        } else {
          players.textContent = `Vez de ${playerOne}`
          currentPlayer = playerTwo;
          cell.textContent = `O`;
          currentPlayer = false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
}


function checkWinner() {
  for (let combination of winCombinations) {
    let [a, b, c] = combination.map(index => board[index])
    // O map irá iterar sobre os índices que
    // foram presentes na combinaçao específica. Se o index da jogada foi, por ex, 3, 4, 5
    // combination é igual a 3,4,5 e o index [3,4,5,] que é responsável por verificar se os
    // quadrados foram preenchidos

    if (a !== `` && a === b && b === c) {
      // se os valores forem iguais e não vazios, temos um vencedor
      if (a === `X`) {
        players.textContent = `${playerOne} Won!`
      } else {
        players.textContent = `${playerTwo} Won!`
      }
    }
  }

}

function checkSubmit() {
  if (submitOne && submitTwo === true) {
    players.textContent = `Vez de ${playerOne}`
  }
}

game();
.board {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
  gap: 5px;
  margin: 50px auto 0 auto;
  /* Adicionado margem inferior de 0 */
  max-width: fit-content;
  /* Adicionada essa linha */
}

.cell {
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  /* Adicionar essa linha */
  justify-content: center;
  /* Adicionar essa linha */
  align-items: center;
  /* Adicionar essa linha */
  min-height: 100vh;
  /* Adicionar essa linha */
  margin: 0;
  /* Adicionar essa linha */
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Jogo da Velha</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>


  <br> <br>

  <div id="textContent">

    <label for="playerOne">Player Um:</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="playerOne">
    <button type="submit" id="submitNameOne">Submit</button>

    <label for="playerTwo">Player Dois:</label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="playerTwo">
    <button type="submit" id="submitNameTwo">Submit</button>
    <button type="submit">Restart</button>
  </div>

  <div class="board">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>


  <div>
    <br> <br>
    <h1 id="h1Id">Quem são os jogadores?</h1>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js" defer></script>

</body>

</html>




This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with using a debugger.  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

please provide the complete code demostrating the problem. Include all relevant code and HTML

Hey, i put the HTML now, thank you

sure! I'll try too debug this either, thank you david

Please edit your title. Its not relevant. People dont know what "logic of victory" is.. Make it more code based so people will understand. like html error with <a> tag (i know thats not the topic of your question, just a example)

Also, you're supposed  to make it into a stacksnippet for easy viewing. I would edit it but too many pending edits..

You do not have a form element, so you should not use a submit button, but rather just a regular button.

I don't see the board. Did you forget sharing your CSS?

your code doesn't demostrate anything

hey, i put the CSS now, thank you! im sorry for the problems

Happy to help. I see there is already an answer. If the answer does not solve the problem for you, then let me know here in the comment section.

also  idk why you for some reason write your code like this document.getElementById("submitNameOne").addEventListener("click", () => { and then 2 lines after that you write it like this
document.getElementById(submitNameTwo).addEventListener(click, () => {

You are updating players.textContent after checkWinner() call which discards any change to players.textContent made in checkWinner function.
checkWinner()
players.textContent = `Vez de ${playerTwo}`

Easy solution would be making checkWinner return true whenever it finds a winner and the check for checkWinner before setting players.textContent = "Vez de ${playerTwo}"
if (!checkWinner())
  players.textContent = `Vez de ${playerTwo}`

However, I would suggest to restructure your code to make it more readable and rename variables. e.g. playerOne -> playerX, playerTwo -> playerO.
board[index] = isTurnOfPlayerX;
if (isTurnOfPlayerX) {
  currentPlayer = playerX;
  cell.textContent = `X`;
} else {
  currentPlayer = playerO;
  cell.textContent = `O`;
}

if (checkWinner()) {
  players.textContent = `${currentPlayer} Won!`
} else {
  players.textContent = `Vez de ${currentPlayer}`
}
isTurnOfPlayerX = !isTurnOfPlayerX


god... thank you sm for your help. I'll do everything you said. And i still dont believe that i didnt see that i updated players.TextContent AFTER checkWinner() function. Thank you so much

@danilo Feel free to accept my answer
